# Why do my button class items share the same lambda functions?

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I am trying to make my own reusable button class in SFML. This would allow me to create a button and add a callback function to it in order to make the creation of buttons much easier.

Here is my hpp file:

```
#ifndef Button_hpp
#define Button_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "View.hpp"
#include "State.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"
namespace kge {
  class Button: public View{
  private:
    sf::RectangleShape* _buttonOutline;
    sf::RenderWindow* _window;
    sf::Clock _clock;
    std::string _textString;
    sf::Text* _text;
  public:
    Button(Window*, std::string);
    ~Button();
    virtual void update(float td);
    std::function<void(void)> callback;
    void setPosition(float x, float y);
  };
}
#endif /* Button_hpp */
```

And here is where I generate the buttons:

```
_restartButton = new kge::Button(_window, "Restart");
_restartButton->setPosition(getCenterOfScreen().x-((11*fontSize)/2), 300);
_restartButton->callback = ([this](){
  State::instance().currentView = new GameView(this->_window);
  this->_window->setView(State::instance().currentView);
});
_exitButton = new kge::Button(_window, "Quit");
_exitButton->setPosition(getCenterOfScreen().x-((11*fontSize)/2), 500);
_exitButton->callback = ([this](){
  this->_window->close();
});
```

Finally, I tell the button to update and do it's checks in my window update, `button->update(td)`

All my buttons seem to all do the action of the last set callback. In this case, my restart button executes my exit code.

Why is this happening and how would I fix it?

**Edit**

Here is my generation code:

```
#ifndef GameOver_hpp
#define GameOver_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "View.hpp"
#include "Button.hpp"
#include "GameView.hpp"
#include "State.hpp"

namespace kge{
  class View;
};

class GameOver: public kge::View{
private:
  sf::Text* _text;
  kge::Button* _restartButton;
  kge::Button* _exitButton;

  void restartFunction(void){

  }
public:
  GameOver(kge::Window* screen) : View(screen){
    int fontSize = 50;
    _text = new sf::Text();
    _text->setFont(kge::AssetManager::mainBundle().getFontNamed("mainfont"));
    _text->setString("Game Over");
    _text->setCharacterSize(fontSize);
    _text->setPosition(getCenterOfScreen().x-((9*fontSize)/2), 100);
    _text->setFillColor(sf::Color(255,0,0));

    _restartButton = new kge::Button(_window, "Restart");
    _restartButton->setPosition(getCenterOfScreen().x-((11*fontSize)/2), 300);

    _exitButton = new kge::Button(_window, "Quit");
    _exitButton->setPosition(getCenterOfScreen().x-((11*fontSize)/2), 500);

    _restartButton->callback = ([this](){
//      State::instance().currentView = new GameView(this->_window);
//      this->_window->setView(State::instance().currentView);
      puts("Restart");
    });

    _exitButton->callback = ([this](){
//      this->_window->close();
      puts("Restart");
    });


    this->addItemToView(_text);
    this->addItemToView(_restartButton);
    this->addItemToView(_exitButton);
  }

  void update(float td){
    _restartButton->update(td);
    _exitButton->update(td);

  }

  ~GameOver(){
    delete _text;
    delete _restartButton;
  }
};

#endif /* GameOver_hpp */
```

Note, kge::View is just a custom sf::Drawable class (how I create my own "views")

**Edit 2**
Button update function:

```
  void Button::update(float td){
    if(_clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() < 400) return;
    if(!sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) return;
    if(mouseIsIn(*_buttonOutline, _window)){
      callback();
      _clock.restart();
    }
  }
```

Please note: _clock is an sf::Clock that is stored privately in the button class.

Comment: Can you confirm this is happening by attaching a debugger and putting a breakpoint in both lamdbas? That may tell you why this would happen.

Comment: @Botje I can confirm that by using break points, the IDE is showing it's on the correct callback, however it is always doing the exit event. If I remove my exit button, my restart button works just fine.

Comment: @Botje What is interesting is when I puts a message, that message shows correctly and if I remove the this->_window->close(); line, it works.

Comment: Could it be that _all_ callbacks are executing? Show the code that should trigger the callbacks.

Comment: It is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How are you storing buttons? How are you iterating over them and call callbacks? Where is update definition? Where are buttons generated, you are capturing `this` so it happens from some member functions.. and so on.

Comment: @Botje don't think that why though, but no matter the delay I add on the button, for the refresh button, it puts refresh twice.

Comment: Code is updated.

Comment: Well, both your callbacks are printing "Restart" now. You should show the code for `kge::Button::update` as well.

Comment: @Botje Shared the function.

Comment: Okay. stick a `cerr << "CLICK " << this << endl` in that if test. Compare it with the addresses of `_restartButton` and `_exitButton`

Comment: @Botje Inside the labda or button class update function? Guessing inside the button class?

Comment: the if test inside the `Button::update` function. We are still testing the hypothesis that both buttons' callbacks fire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190484/discussion-between-iprogram-and-botje).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved in chat. To summarize, the `mouseIsIn` function that @iProgram posted did not check collision correctly, leading to multiple buttons triggering at the same time.

The original function:

```
bool mouseIsIn(sf::RectangleShape shape, sf::RenderWindow* window){
    sf::FloatRect shapeBounds = shape.getGlobalBounds();
    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window);
    sf::FloatRect mouseRect = sf::FloatRect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, mousePos.x+shapeBounds.width, mousePos.y+shapeBounds.height);
    return mouseRect.intersects(shapeBounds);
}
```

The fixed function:

```
bool mouseIsIn(sf::RectangleShape shape, sf::RenderWindow* window){
    sf::FloatRect shapeBounds = shape.getGlobalBounds();
    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window);
    return shapeBounds.contains(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
}
```